# Update from Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.194.0 (Windows 11 insider version) to Windows 11 stable

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-preview, windows-11-upgrade

I am using Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.194.0 now.

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎07-‎Jul-‎21
OS build    22000.194
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.194.0
```

I want to upgrade it to Windows 11 stable but not getting the option. I have downloaded `Windows11InstallationAssistant` to upgrade it to windows 11 stable version but the app is closing when I open it. How can I upgrade to Windows 11 stable version without losing data and installed software?
[image]

Comment: Check in Update - Windows Insider Program if it tells you that .194 is the most recent version for your computer.

Comment: I had just opted out of the insider program to get the stable version. @John

Comment: If you opted out of Insider Preview builds then you are on the current stable build.

Comment: I don't think it's the stable version as there are a lot of bugs in this one @Ramhound

Comment: @KaziSohan - [Except it’s the current version of Windows 11.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information)

Comment: Which channel are you on?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to upgrade it to Windows 11 stable but not getting the option. I have downloaded Windows11InstallationAssistant to upgrade it to windows 11 stable version but the app is closing when I open it.

You are already on the current stable build.

> How can I upgrade to Windows 11 stable version without losing data and installed software?

If opting out of Insider Preview is not allowing you to leave the Release Preview channel then a clean install is your only solution.

The current version as of October 5th 2021 is 22000.194 according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information). If you question, if you will only receive stable builds, you can download the current Windows 11 ISO and perform an in-place repair install of Windows 11. You will want to unenroll before you perform that in-place upgrade.

> [image]

Comment: I have attached an image. From it, you can see that the last update I got was on 17th September. 16 days before the Windows 11 stable version release.  @Ramhound